# Styles and events not working in marko template

Tags: express, marko

My component is loading fine but the styles are not loading, nor are the events firing. I am following the documentation and no errors are being thrown but it seems I might be missing something fundamental here?

View template rendered with `res.marko`:

```
import Explanation from "./components/explanation.marko";
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <include(Explanation, input.explanation) />
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

`explanation.marko file`:

```
class {
  onExplanationClick() {
    console.log("Explanation clicked");
  }
}

style {
  .explanation-paragraph {
    color: red;
  }
}

<div id="explanation" on-click('onExplanationClick')>
  <for (paragraph in input.content)>
    <p class="explanation-paragraph">${paragraph}</p>
  </for>
</div>
```

Server side:

```
app.get("/explanation/:id", async function(req, res) {
  var explanation = await findExplanation(req.params.id);
  var template = require("../../views/explanation/explanation.marko");
  res.marko(template, { explanation, user: req.user });
});
```

Also using marko/node-require and marko/express.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to explicitly import the `Explanation` component. You canremove the `import` statement and just do the following:

    <explanation ${input.explanation}/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to integrate a module bundler/asset pipeline. In the sample [marko-express](https://github.com/marko-js-samples/marko-express) app we are using [Lasso](https://github.com/lasso-js/lasso) (an asset pipeline + JavaScript module bundler).

There's also another sample app that integrates Webpack: https://github.com/marko-js-samples/marko-webpack

The Marko team supports both Lasso and Webpack, but we recommend Lasso because it is simpler and requires minimal configuration.

Please take a look at the `marko-express` app and feel free to ask questions in our Gitter chat room if you get stuck: https://gitter.im/marko-js/marko

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realised Lasso was required for this, and thanks for the gitter link as well

Comment: Link only answers really aren't helpful. Not sure why this was accepted as an answer.

Comment: @Hybridwebdev It's not only a link, this answer pointed out what I was missing (a module bundler) and directly solved the problem I was having. The link went to some sample code that helped me even more. It was very helpful, that's why I accepted it.